# how to set conditional DirectoryIndex using .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I want to experiment with layouts to see what works and what doesn't. I don't want to do that to all traffic in case something doesn't work. For this I want to redirect parts of the traffic to a separate file. I wanted to do this using .htaccess. My first try was redirecting people with an IP-address ending in 1 or 2 to get the new layout. I wanted to dynamically set the DirectoryIndex to do this.

This is what I have:

```
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

#split 20% of the traffic to go to the alternative layout
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} "*(1|2)$"
RewriteRule .? - [S=4]
RewriteRule ^fb/([^/]+) /fb.php?id=$1 [nc]
RewriteRule ^classic /?layout=classic [QSA,nc]
RewriteRule ^thumbs /?layout=thumbs [QSA,nc]
DirectoryIndex 3.php

#the rest of the traffic goes to the default layout
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} "!(1|2)$"
RewriteRule .? - [S=1]
DirectoryIndex index.php index.html

AddDefaultCharset utf-8
```

This doesn't have the desired effect though, basically I would be thrilled if I could have this pseudo-code in .htaccess:

```
if %{REMOTE_ADDR} matches "*(1|2)$"
   DirectoryIndex 3.php
else
   DirectoryIndex index.php
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**To directly translate this block**:

```
if %{REMOTE_ADDR} matches "*(1|2)$"
   DirectoryIndex 3.php
else
   DirectoryIndex index.php
```

we can use `mod_rewrite` rules like this:

```
# default value of DirectoryIndex
DirectoryIndex index.php

RewriteEngine On

# use 3.php instead if following condition is true
RewriteCond %{REMOTE_ADDR} (1|2)$
RewriteRule ^(.+?/)?index\.php$ $13.php [L,NC]
```